# How to check if Adblocker has blocked a site using terminal (Client side)

Tags: shell-script, ubuntu, openvpn

I am connecting to a VPN server with piehole adblocker using a Ubuntu machine and on Vpn Server, I have blocked some particular sites. When I try to access it with a browser, I am unable to open those sites. But when I hit with curl request or ping that site in the terminal, I am able to get success response.

Is there a way to know from the terminal if a site is blocked or not. And how to get its status code.

Answer (score 0):

Yep ! `nslookup websitename`

```
denis:~ $ nslookup google.com
Server:     127.0.1.1
Address:    127.0.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.com
Address: 216.58.204.142

denis:~ $ nslookup googleadservices.com
Server:     127.0.1.1
Address:    127.0.1.1#53

Name:   googleadservices.com
Address: 0.0.0.0
```

Comment: thanks, your answer also worked. I used curl -sL $url -w "%{url_effective}, %{http_code}"  -o /dev/null  to get the required response code